# Setting the value of an input field in antd react JS

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to set the value of a field based on what I have in the database. Make it in-editable but also want the ability for customers to copy that value.

I am able to set the form field values now- but I am unable to use the copy clipboard feature.

```
    const APIAccess = ({product_id}) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const dbvalues =  "adsd";
  const clientIdRef = useRef();
  const [isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState(false);
  const {
    token: { colorBgContainer },
  } = theme.useToken();

    const copyClientId = () => {
      const clientId = clientIdRef.current.value;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(clientId);
  
      setIsCopied(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsCopied(false);
      }, 1000);
    };
  
    
    return (

<Form
    name="control-hooks"
    initialValues={{
    clientID: dbvalues,}}
    form={form} 
  >
   
    <Form.Item
         label="Your Client ID"
         name="clientID"
         ref={clientIdRef} 
 > 
        <Space>
 <Input  type="text" value={dbvalues} /> 
<Tooltip title="copy your Client ID">      
        <Button icon={isCopied ? <CheckSquareOutlined /> : <CopyOutlined />} onClick={copyClientId} /> </Tooltip>
      </Space>
  </Form.Item>   
      <Form.Item
         label="Your Client Secret"
         name="clientSecret"
 >
  </Form>


      );
  }
```

export default APIAccess;
[image: I want to display the values in the fields and when user clicks on copy icon it copys to clipboard]

Comment: Hello, are you sure that await work correctly in your APIAccess Component ?

Comment: I just added it as a place holder...assuming ill get that to work, I want to show the values in text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to programmatically set each initial value. Instead, pass all the initial values to the Form component:

```
<Form
initialValues={{
   clientID: some_client_id,
}}
/>
```

As for copying the value of the input field to the clipboard, use the `useForm()` hook provided by antd.

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Form, Input } from "antd";
import { CopyOutlined, CheckSquareOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

export default function App() {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState(false);

  const copyClientId = () => {
    const clientId = form.getFieldValue("clientId");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(clientId);

    setIsCopied(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsCopied(false);
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Form
        form={form}
        name="basic"
        labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
        wrapperCol={{ span: 16 }}
        style={{ maxWidth: 600 }}
        initialValues={{
          clientId: "9834fh3fh439f348hf94",
        }}
      >
        <Form.Item label="Client ID" name="clientId">
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 8, span: 16 }}>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            htmlType="button"
            icon={isCopied ? <CheckSquareOutlined /> : <CopyOutlined />}
            onClick={copyClientId}
          >
            Copy
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Be sure to pass `form` as a prop to the `<Form>` component.

I added the icon change as a bonus! You always want to indicate to the user that an action has taken place.

Comment: How do I copy it to clipboard?

Comment: navigator.clipboard.writeText(clientID)

Comment: That didnt work. I have updated my code.

Comment: What didn't work? The copy function or setting the initial values? Looks like you put 'clientID' in there as a string, not as the variable reference. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I was able to set the default values. However, I am unable to copy the values to clipboard.  onClick={() => {navigator.clipboard.writeText(clientID)} } I tried it without the quotes as well.  The error I get is that clientID is not defined.

Comment: Did you see my updated solution with `useRef()`?

Comment: That did not work either.

Comment: updated the code to reflect your solution

Comment: Ok I read up on antd and spun up a codepen for ya. You have to use the useForm() hook provided by antd. The edit queue is full so I'll update my answer later. Check out [this codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-5-2-2-forked-7hznh5?file=/demo.tsx).

Comment: Im going to try it now..